# How can you create a custom InlineEntityElementHandler in Wagtail CMS?

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I'm trying to create a custom rich text feature which mimics the behaviour of richtext's link feature.

The only differences are another name, and adding a class to it. Because we need two different types of links in the frontend (Headless setup). And it's essential that we have the Link Chooser interface (Page, external, email etc.).

I tried the following, but now both Link handlers (built-in and custom) have the "arrow" class:

```
@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_arrow_link(features):
    feature_name = 'arrow'
    type_ = 'LINK'
    tag = 'a class="arrow"'

    control = {
        'type': type_,
        'label': '->',
        'description': 'Arrow Link',
    }

    features.register_editor_plugin(
        'draftail', feature_name, draftail_features.EntityFeature(control)
    )

    db_conversion = {
        'from_database_format': {tag: InlineEntityElementHandler(type_)},
        'to_database_format': {'entity_decorators': {type_: tag}}
    }

    features.register_converter_rule('contentstate', feature_name, db_conversion)
    features.default_features.append(feature_name)
```

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation in your code snippet? And I am wondering if you should be using `register_link_type` here. https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/extending/rich_text_internals.html#FeatureRegistry.register_link_type

Comment: @cnk I fixed the indentation. As far as I understood the `register_link_type` would only rewrite a handler, but not create a new link itself. [register_link_type](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/rich_text_internals.html#FeatureRegistry.register_link_type)